# Free Cloud Storage to host MS Sql

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud

Are there any free cloud storages such as Amazon cloud, google cloud, etc.. that would allow me to host live ms sql databases on. I guess in better words, is there such thing as a free 3rd party type software like Azure? And then with that I would use it in Visual Studio for applications. Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: This question seems to be more about hosting than about programming. I suggest posting on another site, perhaps serverfault or dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot host MS SQL on Amazon, google or Microsoft storage. To run MS SQL server on cloud - you have folllowing options:

1. Run it on Azure VM roles
2. Run it as Windows Azure SQL Database
3. Run it on Amazon RDS
4. Run it on AMAZON VM's
5. And on other IaaS/DBaaS

Although, each option that I mention has free tier - they are not free if you go above free tier.

Comment: What if I wanted to run something from my home? Could I make my own Minny cloud or is there another way I could set up something so that I can create a small live ms sql server? As u can tell, I have very little knowledge about this topic. Thanks for answer/

Comment: Technically - Yes. It's called "private cloud" http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/cloud-computing/private-cloud.aspx

Comment: But since I do not know your requirements, I can't comment on whether it's right for you or not. And regarding running locally - you could setup a sql server installation but that my require you to perform tasks like - buy hardware, buy server os, buy sql server license, setting it up among other things.

Comment: And also search for "hosted MS SQL" for services like this: http://www.discountasp.net/sp_sqlhosting.aspx - Again, I do not know your requirement and i cannot suggest with certainty what you can do. I hope this helped.

Comment: FYI: Due to the Pace at which cloud vendor evolve, there has been changes. for instance: you can run SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machine now.